# BIRT 4.7 doesn't have maven central repository

Tags: birt

BIRT version 4.7 doesn't have maven central repository. I could see they have repository till version 4.6, after that no repository. Any reason why this version doesn't have repository? or Will it be available in any near future? or Are they moving community to commercial?

Comment: Have you ask the developers these questions?

Comment: @reporter, developers have been asked using official comunity forum. Nobody answered. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1091915/